# Push route from within action in Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

Trying to push route change from within the store. I tried importing `router` into the store itself and then doing something along the lines of:

```
LOG_OUT({commit}){
  commit('LOG_OUT__MUTATION');

  router.push({
   name: 'Login' 
  })
}
```

... but that didn't work.

I also don't want to push a route change from directly with the components because it would mean I need to check authentication and push a route change in every component, which seems cumbersome to me.

Edited:

The `LOG_OUT__MUTATION` clears the token stored in the state.

Comment: please explain and include the `LOG_OUT__MUTATION` code

Comment: Just edited my question :) it basically just clears the Auth token from the store.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, it is going to the login view page, before commiting to the store right? that means router is pushing before the commit, hence this is an async problem.

Comment: No, it wipes the token from the store, THEN redirects to login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

**Final Implementation**

In your `store`, simply import the `router`:

```
import router from '@/router/index'

actions: {

  LOG_OUT({commit}){
    commit('LOG_OUT__MUTATION');

    router.push({
      name:'Login'
    })
  }

}
```

And then from another part of my app, I simply imported `store` and dispatched an action:

```
import Store from '@/store/store'

myFunction () {
  Store.dispatch('LOG_OUT');
}
```

---

**Initial Implementation**

Here was my implementation of Daksh Miglani's solution (which works). In my store.js, I had:

```
export const forceLogout = (commit) => {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('LOG_OUT__MUTATION');
    resolve();
  })

}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions,
  mutation
})
```

And then in another part of the app (helpers.js), I had:

```
import Store from '@/store/store'
import { forceLogout } from '@/store/store'
import router from '@/router/index'

forceLogout(Store.commit)
  .then(() => {
    debugger;
    router.push({
      name:'Login'
    })

  }).catch((error) => {
     console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: when we include the router in Vue instance, is not it available  everywhere inside the app even Vuex?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have a solution for you buddy:

So firstly you write a store committing function like this:

```
export const commitLogout = ({commit}) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('LOG_OUT__MUTATION');
    // once you're done with your clearing, resolve or reject the promise
    resolve();
  });
}
```

This function will return a promise, that you can use in your logging out function which will at the end allow you to commit and clear first and then logout.

Then you use this function as your logout function:

```
...

  logout() {
    commitLogout().then(() => {
      this.$router.push({
       name: 'Login' 
      })
    })
  }

...
```

Comment: Ok, so I get this. Makes sense. How do I access the `router` function from outside a component though? I wanted to actively avoid doing it that way because it would mean I need to store the logout validation in every component.

Comment: @Modermo edited my code, this.$router is a mapping to router.

Comment: or Vue.prototype.$router, which is technically this.$router

Comment: Calling  `Vue.prototype.$router` from within the `LOG_OUT` action just returns `undefined`. `Vue` is being imported, so I'm not sure what gives here.

Comment: try vue-router-sync, available on npm